# Spring mechanical losses calculation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, spring, simulations

A real spring (having damping losses), attached with a mass is stretched for a distance of x mm from its equilibrium, then what is the distance it will cover on the other side when released from this position. And what other variables do i need to calculate this distance theoretically considering damping losses? Can Ansys simulation able to provide the precise distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that it's a horizontal mass-spring system, then the Newtonian equation of motion is:

$$ma=-kx$$

Or:

$$\ddot{x}+\frac{k}{m} x=0$$

With:

$$\omega^2=\frac{k}{m}$$

the solution is:

$$x=A\sin(\omega t+\varphi)$$

We have two initial conditions:

$$x(0)=x_0\text{ and }\dot{x}(0)=0$$
so that:
$$\dot{x}(0)=A\omega\cos(0+\varphi)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow \cos\varphi=0 \Rightarrow \varphi=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
and:
$$x(0)=A\sin(\pi/2)=x_0\Rightarrow A=x_0$$

So:

$$x(t)=x_0\sin(\omega t+\pi/2)$$

This means that in the *absolute absence of friction* the mass $m$ moves from $x=x_0$ to $x=-x_0$ (over half a period of oscillation) **because the mass moves as a simple harmonic oscillator with amplitude** $A=x_0$.

Comment: Sir, i was asking about a real spring in real scenario, that's considering the mechanical and drag losses of spring energy, how can we find the exact position of spring displacement? Thank you!

Comment: In that case you have to specify the damping factor: **I cannot be expected to divine that!**

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! But how can I find the damping factor of the spring or at least predict it's approx value theoretically, if i have other design parameters of the spring.

Comment: What you need to do is add any detail you have about the problem into your question. Someone who answers the question will use these to determine the damping factor.

Comment: It's for a project, where i have designed a spring (spring constant=k, no. of turns=n, inner diameter=d, spring ratio=C, shear modulus=G, mean dia= D) and i want to theoretically predict its motion. And in order to do that, I am seeking a general expression or a theoretical way to find the damping factor if i have the above parameters. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: What you describe is a *perfect*, Hookean spring, with no damping. Any damping would come from air drag (on the mass) or friction of the mass on some surface that it moves on.

Comment: Is there any theoretical way to find the intrinsic energy losses of a real spring? i.e. If a spring is given 'x' displacement, that's (1/2kx^2) potential energy, so how much energy it will lose as its internal friction energy while going back?

Comment: You could google for 'hysteresis of a spring'.

Comment: There is nothing helpful i can find about intrinsic losses calculation of spring. I will be really thankful if you can provide any helpful link. Thank you!